# REACT-REDUX : Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Below is the code to fetch movies using React-Redux. I have used fetch() to fetch thedata from API, but i got the error as "Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

**HomeAction.js**

```
import {API_URL,  API_KEY} from '../config'; 

export function getMovies(movies)
{
    return function(dispatch){
    const url =`${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-us&page=1`; 
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())  
      .then(function(data){
        dispatch({type:"GET_MOVIES", payload:data.results})
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        dispatch({type:"GET_MOVIES", payload:err})
      })
    }  
}
```

**HomeReducer.js**

```
export function HomeReducer(state ={
            },action)
{
    console.log(action);
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case "GET_MOVIES" : 
           return {...state,...action.payload};
           break;
       default : 
       break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//redux 
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {createLogger} from "redux-logger";
//to connect to react and redux
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

//STEP 3
import reducers from './Reducers/indexReducer';


import App from './App';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(createLogger());

//STEP 1
const store = createStore(reducers,middleware);

ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>     
    <App />
    </Provider> 
    ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

So i have tried to use axios by browing and tried to use redux-thunk but i got the same error. Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: You should read [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) tutorial as Actions are not supposed to use like that. Redux is just a store for **getting** and **setting** data, you don't make calls anywhere and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using redux you have to return a plain js object see this guide [enter link description here](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions)

for ex:

```
{
   type: ADD_TODO,
   text: 'Build my first Redux app'
}
```

in your case to perform a async action you simply use a middleware [see this](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use actions as indicated by you (async actions), then you need to use the `redux-thunk` package. To do this, first install it:

```js
npm install --save redux-thunk
```

Next, connect it as middleware to your store:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import reducers from './Reducers/indexReducer';

import App from './App';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(createLogger(), thunk);

const store = createStore(reducers, middleware);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>     
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

After that, you can use your event as you would like, that is:

```
store.dispatch(getMovies(/* args */));
```

[You can learn more about this here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk)

[And here you can see an example.](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#example-using-thunk-middleware-for-async-actions)

Comment: Hi @Rustum, Can you mention where i need to add store.dispatch() in actions or reducers ?

Comment: Most likely, you will need this in your components, from where you plan to trigger events. Of course, usually `dispatch` is not used directly with the `store`, but through `mapDispatchToProps`. I gave this example so that it is clear that now you can call `getMovies` as an asynchronous event, although by default, without `redux-thunk`, `redux` does not allow this.